# PowerShell 2 Get Folder from Path?

Tags: powershell-2.0

Path example: 'C:\folderA\folderB\folderC\script.ps1'

Using `Split-Path`, I'm able to get 'folderC', but how would I get 'folderB'?

```
Split-Path (Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent) -Leaf
```

This returns folderC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could just add another `Split-Path`

```
Split-Path (Split-Path (Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent) -Parent) -Leaf
```

as pipeline it would look like this

```
Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent |  
    Split-Path -Parent |
    Split-Path -Leaf
```